# Draggable map - JQuery or HTML5

Tags: jquery, html

Someone knows a JQuery plugin (may be something in HTML5) to create a map with elements that can be draggable?

Like image[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is this fantastic jQuery : [Arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/)

Apart from this (depending upon your use):

[ImageMapster](https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster)

[Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Though, it will take you some time getting used to it.